# Lua: If no value, then create value in table - What am I missing?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have an issue that I've spent hours trying to figure out, but since Lua is still relatively new to me, I can't figure out why it's not working.

Here's what I'm trying to do.  If I'm spiking an item for the first time, it won't show up in the spikeRates table, so I need to add it.  If I've spiked the item before, but never with the item I'm spiking with, then I need to reflect that in the spikeRates[itemSpiked] table.  The code I've written up is as follows, but fails to populate the table.

```
spikeRates={}
itemSpiked = "leather"
mySpike = "iron"

if not spikeRates[itemSpiked] then
   spikeRates[itemSpiked]={}
   spikeRates[itemSpiked][mySpike]={}
   print("This is your first time spiking "..itemSpiked.."!") 
 elseif not spikeRates[itemSpiked][mySpike] then 
   spikeRates[itemSpiked][mySpike]={Failure=0,Success=0} 
   print("This is your first time spiking "..itemSpiked.." with "..mySpike.."!")
end

for i,v in pairs(spikeRates) do 
  print(i .. ": " .. v) 
end
```

When that's run, I get an error of trying to concatenate a nil value (v) for the printing of the database.  Everything looks correct, or so I thought.  Am I missing something completely obvious?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The if-else logic seems a bit confusing. Try separating it into two ifs, like so:

```
spikeRates={}

itemSpiked = "leather"
mySpike = "iron"

if not spikeRates[itemSpiked] then
  spikeRates[itemSpiked]={}
  print("This is your first time spiking "..itemSpiked.."!")
end 
if not spikeRates[itemSpiked][mySpike] then 
  spikeRates[itemSpiked][mySpike]={Failure=0,Success=0} 
  print("This is your first time spiking "..itemSpiked.." with "..mySpike.."!")
end

for i,v in pairs(spikeRates) do 
  print(i .. ": " .. v) 
end
```

If you don't need the debug prints, here's a simpler version with no ifs at all:

```
spikeRates={}

itemSpiked = "leather"
mySpike = "iron"

spikeRates[itemSpiked] = spikeRates[itemSpiked] or {}
spikeRates[itemSpiked][mySpike] = spikeRates[itemSpiked][mySpike] or {Failure=0,Success=0} 

for i,v in pairs(spikeRates) do 
  print(i .. ": " .. v) 
end
```

This `variable = variable or defaultValue` is a very common idiom in Lua, you will see it very often.

Comment: Good answer. A small note: if you're feeling confident and want to include the debug prints, you can do this: `spikeRates[itemSpiked] = spikeRates[itemSpiked] or print("This is your first time spiking "..itemSpiked.."!") or {}`. Ignore this if you are confused.

Comment: he, that's a nice one Deco, never thought of doing it that way!

Comment: The print messages are definitely needed.  It's an output to the user so they are aware, and the reason for the elseif portion was so that it would output whether they've spiked that item at all in the past, and if they had, move on to see if they'd spiked it with that particular spike.  I tried both in wxluaedit, and it still returns an error for trying to concatenate a nil (v) value.  Not sure what the issue is...

Comment: Actually, it does work, but it seems that the final print does not work.  For some reason, the v is not showing as a valid value.  Any idea why?  Edit: It's because it's a table value.  Duh...  Any easy way to dump the table out as such: leather : iron (0 Failure, 0 Success), steel (0 Failure, 0 Success) -- etc, given that it can vary in the spikes used?

Comment: sure - here's my lib to dump tables to a string: https://github.com/kikito/inspect.lua